# How to view a Windows form application in a browser?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html, visual-studio-2012, object-tag

I have a Windows application which I went further to convert to a `.dll` file using control library project.

Now I want to be able to host the control on a website using a `.html` page. I've used the following links and still have issues with viewing the control in my browser.

[site2](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20021205.asp)

[site3](https://weblogs.asp.net/spano/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page)

I tried to write the `<object>` tag seen in site2, and I think that's where my problem started. The folder containing both the HTML doc and `.dll` file are located in `C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\TheFolder`. So how do I convert this to contain the "localhost" link as seen in "site2"?

Also, how to I locate the route to alter my security policy (Control Panel > Administrative Tools > .net Framework Configuration > Configure Code Access Security Policy > Adjust Zone Security), as I can't locate ".net framework configuration" when I navigate to "administrative tools".

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer thank you for the post, but I don't seem to understand the rationale behind it. When you posted "please refrain from adding this to your post", what exactly were you referring to? I didn't add in any way that my question demands an urgent answer. Or am I getting it all wrong? I'll be glad if you could have at least highlighted the region that prompted your link.

Comment: Code Access Security Policy is gone in .Net 4. IE hosting is also disabled by default in .Net 4. Unless you have control over user's machines I suggest you to move to ClickOnce.

Comment: @halfer oh I'm so sorry about that. Thanks for the observation and clarification. I forgot I added that initially.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 thanks a lot. I also explored click once. But my inexperience is making me do something wrong that I can't figure out. For click once, do I need to configure a HTML document using the <object> tag, so my control is available on browser?

Comment: no visual studio will generate the html document for you.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 thanks a lot, but what I meant was do I need to add it as a new item, and then set the <object> tag? If yes, please use my folder path to put me through on what my <object> tag will look like. I'm really new to this, so please pardon my inexperienced method of asking the questions as well as going about solving the problem.

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-using-the-publish-wizard

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 thanks for your input so far. I followed the steps in the link to publish my windows app online. But when I loaded localhost in my browser, I got a blank page. Not even an error message was there, just a plain white page.  I believe there is something I'm either not doing, or I'm not doing right.

Comment: if you publish via the wizard you should enter http://localhost/publishlocation/publish.htm

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 thanks a lot for that. I used that and was able to see the publish.htm file in my browser. However, when I click the "launch" link or "run" button in the browser, I get an error message relating to the prerequisite files not found (I think I can handle that). Please permit me to ask: if this issue explained previously is sorted out, can my application run in the browser, or it'll have to download the app and run on the client's machine?

Comment: no a clickonce app would run outside the browser. the browser just launch the app via a url.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 forgive the long silence, as I had to tidy up the software and deploy - it's about 99% complete. Thanks a lot for the clarification above. I guess one click is the closest option to what I actually needed.